# BufferedReader waits for 30 seconds after reading an empty line

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

After opening socket and sending request got immediate from third party system in InputStreamReader. Reading line by line through while loop response and get headers read in the same second and at the end an empty line before response body. But system waits for exactly 30 seconds after reading that empty line.

```java
String path = "/System";
wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
wr.write("content-type: text/xml\r\n");
wr.write("\r\n");
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line != null && line.startsWith("<?xml")) { 
        startreading = true;
    }
    if (startreading) { 
        response += line;
    }
}
wr.close();
rd.close();
socket.close();

//Response
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:91]  response packet : java.io.BufferedReader@6d613c74
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:93] bufferreader not null
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:100]  line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:102]  line : Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:53:49 GMT
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:104]  line : X-Powered-By: abc
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:106]  line : Server: abcbcbcbbc.asdsadas
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:108]  line : Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=e38jasdsadsadsada1wyf9q;Path=/
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:110]  line : Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:112]  line : Content-Type: text/xml
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:114]  line : Content-Length: ***
[2019-05-14 18:59:12 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:116]  line :
[2019-05-14 18:59:42 INFO-SUBAPP SendRequest:118]  line : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodResponse><params><param><value>
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question using the proper formatting, this will help others to read what you did.

Comment: This is all your code ? Where are the trace lines coming from ? I guess you don't close a stream properly and the 30s is any timeout ...

Comment: Trace lines are copied from logs created, code for logs was removed and only actual code posted here. Related to stream close, are you refering to buffered reader close than it is done at the end wr.close and rd.close. isn't this the right way to close??